# Yii, several instances of model in one form

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii

We have two models

```
class Base extends AbstractModel
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'table_base';
    }
}

class ExtendBase extends AbstractModel
{
    public $id;
    public $baseID;

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'table_base_extend';
    }
}
```

I won't describe all, will describe only main things.

So, now I want create form that will combine this forms. And want in action do something like this

```
public function actionSome ()
{
    $oBase = new Base();
    $aExtendBase = array(); // important this is array

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $aExtendBase[] = new Extend(); // fill in array, pre-create for form
    }

    if ($this->isPost()) { // protected custom method
        if (isset($_POST['Base'], $_POST['ExtendBase'])) // here should be specific checker because we have several ExtendBase instances in form
        {
            // save Base model
            // save each ExtendBase model
        }
    }

    $this->render('formView', array('oBase' => $oBase, 'aExtendBase' => $aExtendBaes))
}
```

So question is

1. How to create such 'combined' form in view;
2. How to get all forms data (I mean each) after POST action;

Answer (score 0):

See the solution on the Yii WIKI

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

Comment: It will work only if we have different models. But we have same, so it won't work in our case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model (`CFormModel`) which does not represent an `ActiveRecord` just for a single form.

I think it would be the best way for you to proceed (assuming I've understood your problem correctly).

If I were you, I would create a Model to represent the rules for this form only (like I said, an instance of `CFormModel`, not `ActiveRecord`) and then, in your controller, take the elements that got submitted and manually create and/or update objects for both classes.